# Cannot display horizontally in html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I used the sample code and simply saved as .html.
But the second part cannot display horizontally
I tried to google this similar issue, but not much solution.
Please help!!

Code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">Full width</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">25%</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">25%</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">50%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it's your code in its entirety it lacks the concept of `container`. Put your `row` in a `<div class = "container">` then close after the end of the row your `</div>`

Comment: Can you post your css too? Ideally it can be done using display: inline-block; and specifying width.

Comment: Did you import Bootstrap properly? To check that, you can open inspector in browser and look inside `head` tag. If there is something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/bootstrap/css">` -> mouse 2 -> open in new tab. And there should be a lot of text, it's Bootstrap's code, if so, everything is imported properly

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have imported `bootstrap.css` as because `col-md-*` and `row` classes are part of bootstrap. Check below snippet for reference.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">Full width</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">25%</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">25%</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">50%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use classes like `row` and `col-md-*`, you need to connect Bootstrap Twitter to your html which has these classes already.

Just paste this code in your head tag before your style.css:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css